# Impossible to convert correctly json string to object with Gson

Tags: java, json, spring, gson, deserialization

It is very strange, it should be simple, but i don't know why, i'm not able to transform my string json to object.

The JSON string:

```json
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "Transaction fetched successfully",
  "data": {
    "id": 4576711,
    "tx_ref": "efe4e0da-192c-406e-acf4-aeb118a2c700",
    "flw_ref": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "device_fingerprint": "3db1a1db1ca4f052bc40fb464b0d0750",
    "amount": 150,
    "currency": "XOF",
    "charged_amount": 150,
    "app_fee": 2.1,
    "merchant_fee": 0,
    "processor_response": "Transaction Successful",
    "auth_model": "AUTH",
    "ip": "54.75.161.64",
    "narration": "XXXXX_XXXXXX",
    "status": "successful",
    "payment_type": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "created_at": "2023-09-05T11:14:13.000Z",
    "account_id": 1851620,
    "meta": {
      "__CheckoutInitAddress": "https://ravemodal-dev.herokuapp.com/v3/hosted/pay",
      "typeRequest": "PASS_SUBSCRIPTION"
    },
    "amount_settled": 147.9,
    "customer": {
      "id": 2156304,
      "name": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "phone_number": "221123456789",
      "email": "sav@XXXXX.XXXX",
      "created_at": "2023-07-26T00:10:17.000Z"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to convert to the object `FlwCashoutCallbackDto` and this object is

```java
public class FlwCashoutCallbackDto  {
    private String event;
    private Data data;  
    private Customer customer;
    private Meta meta;
    
    @JsonProperty("event.type")
    private String eventType;
    
    private String message;
    private String status;
}
```

The the `Meta` class:

```java
public class Meta {
    private String __CheckoutInitAddress;
    private String typeRequest; // use to know how to redirect
}
```

The `Data` class:

```java
public class Data {
    private int id;
    
    @JsonProperty("tx_ref")
    private String txRef;
    @JsonProperty("flw_ref")
    private String flwRef;
    @JsonProperty("device_fingerprint")
    private String deviceFingerprint;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String currency;
    @JsonProperty("charged_amount")
    private BigDecimal chargedAmount;
    @JsonProperty("app_fee")
    private BigDecimal appFee;
    @JsonProperty("merchant_fee")
    private BigDecimal merchantFee;
    @JsonProperty("processor_response")
    private String processorResponse;
    @JsonProperty("auth_model")
    private String authModel;
    
    private String ip;
    private String narration;
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("payment_type")
    private String paymentType;
    @JsonProperty("created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
    @JsonProperty("account_id")
    private int accountId;
    
    private Customer customer;
}
```

But when I try to convert to `FlwCashoutCallbackDto`, Meta is `Null` and many properties inside Data missing and i have this result

> FlwCashoutCallbackDto(event=null, data=Data(id=XXXXXX, txRef=null, flwRef=null, deviceFingerprint=null, amount=150, currency=XOF, chargedAmount=null, appFee=null, merchantFee=null, processorResponse=null, authModel=null, ip=54.75.161.64, narration=Gara France, status=successful, paymentType=null, createdAt=null, accountId=0, customer=Customer(id=2156304, name=XXXX, phoneNumber=null, email=sav@gara.store)), customer=null, meta=null, eventType=null, message=Transaction fetched successfully, status=success)

My code is just this :

```java
String data = "{\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"Transaction fetched successfully\",\"data\":{\"id\":4576711,\"tx_ref\":\"efe4e0da-192c-406e-acf4-aeb118a2c700\",\"flw_ref\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"device_fingerprint\":\"3db1a1db1ca4f052bc40fb464b0d0750\",\"amount\":150,\"currency\":\"XOF\",\"charged_amount\":150,\"app_fee\":2.1,\"merchant_fee\":0,\"processor_response\":\"Transaction Successful\",\"auth_model\":\"AUTH\",\"ip\":\"54.75.161.64\",\"narration\":\"Gara France\",\"status\":\"successful\",\"payment_type\":\"XXXXXXXX\",\"created_at\":\"2023-09-05T11:14:13.000Z\",\"account_id\":1851620,\"meta\":{\"__CheckoutInitAddress\":\"https://ravemodal-dev.herokuapp.com/v3/hosted/pay\",\"typeRequest\":\"PASS_SUBSCRIPTION\"},\"amount_settled\":147.9,\"customer\":{\"id\":2156304,\"name\":\"XXXXX\",\"phone_number\":\"221123456789\",\"email\":\"XXXXX\",\"created_at\":\"2023-07-26T00:10:17.000Z\"}}}";
        
FlwCashoutCallbackDto callbackDto = new Gson().fromJson(data, FlwCashoutCallbackDto.class);
```

With data containing the initial JSON string.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `Meta` and `Customer` are children of `Data` and should be moved to that class

Comment: @QBrute thank you very much. I spent hours on it. TY. Please last question, why     `@JsonProperty("tx_ref")
    private String txRef;` is not converted and null in the object ?

Comment: `@JsonProperty` is from Jackson. You're using Gson, so you need `@SerializedName`. Please read the [documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html)

Comment: Perfect, i reuse Jackson, add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on object and works. Thank you